# Fancybox: cannot scroll on Android phones

Tags: android, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

I am using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to output the results of a calculator on my website: [inlandprotitle.com](http://inlandprotitle.com)

Output looks good on desktop and iphone using:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Output is cropped on android phones.

Is there some way to enable fancybox scrolling on an android phone?

Comment: have you tried just using the original fancybox? Right know you are loading both, the original version and the easy-fancybox wp plugin .... just to make sure they are not conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into SO much trouble doing this as well. The answer is, it depends. What Android OS are you testing on? Is it 2.X?

Answer (score 0):

Some functions on different devices are not available so it wouldn't work. The best thing to do is check the android spec's and also test it on different android devices